# Welcome flash message after sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

When users sign up to my application I have a welcome message appear on the home page using Devise's `sign_in_count` column.

```
def home
 if current_user.sign_in_count == 1 
  flash.now[:notice] = "Welcome!"
 end
end
```

The only problem though is it stays there until they sign out and sign back in. How can I make it show only once and disappear when the page is refreshed or changed? Is there some rails way to do this?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

application.html.erb

```
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <%= render "shared/flash_message" %>
    <%= yield %>
 </div>
</body>
```

_flash_message.html.erb

```
<% [:notice, :error, :alert].each do |level| %>
 <% unless flash[level].blank? %>
  <div class="span12">
   <div class="<%= flash_class(level) %> fade in">
    <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">×</a>
     <%= content_tag :p, flash[level] %>
   </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Show the relevant code of your `layouts/application.html.erb` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `layouts/application.html.erb` you should have something like this:

```
<% flash.each do |key,  value| %>
<%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "flash #{key}") %>
<% end %>
```

Doing this way, should works as you expect.

**EDIT**

What if you verify for the `current_user` is already set?

```
def home
 if current_user && current_user.sign_in_count == 1 
  flash.now[:notice] = "Welcome!"
 end
end
```

**EDIT 2**

OK! Got it! The `sign_in_count` column from `Devise` will remain the same until the next login, so, it will always keep showing you the `Welcome!` message. To make this work as you expect you have to create a flag on it.

```
def home
 if current_user && current_user.sign_in_count == 1
  unless session[:display_welcome]
    flash.now[:notice] = "Welcome!"
    session[:display_welcome] = true
  end
 end
end
```

You can try using `session` or `cookies`.

Comment: Are you telling me to set up a flash message? I already have it set up but its different looking since I'm using Twitter-boostrap, but it does have the same functionality. I edited my question to let you see.

Comment: It still does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, never would have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

If the user logs in for the first time, change the logic to compare `against 0`. After setting flash message update the sign_in_count to 1,

```
def home
 if current_user.sign_in_count == 0 
  flash.now[:notice] = "Welcome!"
  current_user.update_attribute(:sign_in_count, 1)
 end
end
```

Comment: The issue with this is it keeps the `:sign_in_count` at 1 forever. In my case I had to do `(:sign_in_count, 2)` because when you register the user is already at 1.